# Rebasing a core repo in git

Tags: git

I have a customized fork of CodeIgniter that I use as a standard baseline for several projects.  Recently, I've made significant improvements in this repo that I want to use to update the client projects that use it.  What I can't seem to figure out is how to pull in the changes to a client project.

So I have:

```
Baseline:
A--B--C--D--E

Client cloned @ C
C'--D'--E'
```

And I want to update the client repo to E from the Baseline project.

I've tried rebase, and it has erased the files not present in the baseline project (views and such), and creates a bunch of conflicts that really don't need to be conflicts with things like the default HTML5 boilerplate that I use.

Is there an option for rebase that I should be using?  Is there a different way to approach it?  Do I need a bunch of .gitignores for the content directories?

Comment: Can you include precisely the commands that you ran? Also, I assume you don't actually want to ignore the content directories?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably start looking into merging instead of rebasing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should think in terms of branches, instead of repos.
A fork is just a branch derived from another branch. The two have an ancestor in common (a commit) and that's what allows you to do all the nice git magic.

If i understand correctly your situation is more like

```
(origin/master)
A--B--C--D--E
      \
       \
        \F--G
        (local/master)
```

and you want to have commits `D--E` in `your local branch`, amirite?

Then you either have to `git rebase origin/master`, or `git merge origin/master`.

Think of it graphically and it'll be a lot easier.

And yes, you should most definitely [read some more](http://progit.org/book/ch3-0.html) about git's branching model :)